# Request works in POSTMAN but not by FETCH

Tags: node.js, fetch, postman

I am running into some trouble trying to figure out why my request is working on postman but not in the app (using fetchjs).
The following is my request in the postman:
[image]

The Following is my code in node app using fetchjs:

```
fetchData() {
    let body = {}
    let method = "read";
    let id = "ctzeN5gn5fkQqj9uc";
    let vals = [method,{},id];
    let headers={
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/v1/en/reviews', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:headers,
        dataType:'json',
        body: JSON.stringify({vals:vals})
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.error) throw (res.reason);
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch(res => console.error(res))
}
```

The Following is my express server code:

```
let vals = this.req.body.vals;
if (!vals) throw new Error('Vals Missing');
let vals = JSON.parse(vals);
let method = vals[0];          //>>>error here (Unexpected token r)
let args = vals[1];
let id = vals[2];
```

I get the following response back :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token r"
```

the r is actually part of method (read).

Any idea on what i am doing wrong ? Any Suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: any error in the browser console? this might be a CORS issue.

Comment: Hi I updated above, and it is actually not a cors issue , i am using app.user(cors()) in the express server already.

Comment: On what line is the error?

Comment: Hey guys!  I just updated my code with the server side that's throwing me an error, its on let method = vals[0]

Comment: Did you checked what value you are getting here `let vals = JSON.parse(vals);` for `vals` ?. I think you are getting a string instead of an array.

Comment: Is the JSON validated ? Missing double quotes anywhere ?

Comment: Yes it's actually works when I use post man. But for the fetch request it somehow treats it differently?

Comment: Have you checked this ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35852192/uncaught-in-promise-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-fetch-function

Comment: Check that the datatype of `this.req.body.vals` is actually a string and not an object - express might have already parsed the JSON string to objects because the content-type is `"application/json"`. If that's the case then you would be trying to parse the already parsed objects and getting that error.

Comment: @Sly_cardinal thats what excatly happened. Thanks a lot.i removed the JSON.parse() and it worked . But now my postman doesnot work. Should i skip that header and send something else ? can you suggest please?

Comment: In my postmain i tried to use content type as "application/json "  and removed  application/x-www-form-urlencoded, i get the error, is there a way around to use postman and app fetch without issue ?

Comment: Just check the data type - if it's a string then parse it, if it's an object then leave it as is and let it through.

Comment: Cheers! i am doing the same currently . Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

In line 5: `let vals = [method,vals,id];` there are two 'vals'?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetchData() {
    let body = {}
    let method = "read";
    let id = "ctzeN5gn5fkQqj9uc";
    let vals = [method,{},id];
    let headers= {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'};

    fetch('http://localhost:8000/v1/en/reviews', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:headers,
        body: JSON.stringify({vals:vals})
      }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            if (res.error) throw (res.reason);
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        })
        .catch(res => console.error(res))
}
```

also

```
let vals = this.req.body.vals;
if (!vals) throw new Error('Vals Missing');
vals = JSON.parse(vals);
let method = vals[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Tried to do the same thing by changing the header content type to application, but i get the error as vals not found , i.e req.body.vals doesnot exists (undefined) but still works the same for the postman ( has same headers). 

 I already have added the   `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());` 
Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: can you tell me  this.req.body.vals; , why this . can you added code?

Comment: ah, you can ignore the this, i am actually creating a class and setting the defaul parameters

`constructor(req,res){
  this.req = req;
  this.res = res;
}`
So the this.req.body.vals is just referring to the current req.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mode: 'cors'` on your options like that:

`fetch("http://localhost:8000/v1/en/reviews", {
      mode: "cors",
      method: "POST",
      headers: headers,
      dataType: "json",
      body: JSON.stringify({vals: vals})
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.error) throw res.reason;
        this.setState({data: res.data});
      })
      .catch((res) => console.error(res));`